# Colocar una imagen de fondo en un div

Tags: html, css

Espero que todos estén bien , este es mi problema : Quiero colocar una imagen de fondo adentro de un div , el inconveniente esta en que la imagen no llena todo el div ni se acopla a su contenido , como lo hago

```css
#fondo{
  background-image: url()/* url de la imagen*/ 
  /*deseo que la imagen se acople a la caja*/
}
```

```html
<div id="fondo"> 
  <p> Relleno</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No entendi mucho la pregunta con lo que entregaste, pero intentaste background-size: cover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero es importante que el contenedor `fondo` tenga una medida fija en ambos lados: **width** y **height**.

Segundo, la URL de la imagen debe ser entre paréntesis y entre comillas.

Tercero, la imagen debe ser de `background-size:`  **cover** ó con medida específica con respecto al contenedor: **100%** o en pixeles.

```css
#fondo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/480/people");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="fondo"> 
  <p> Relleno</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No olvides marcar con ✓ si te ayudo.